# Does appending value in setParameter of a named query increase possibility of SQL injection?

Tags: java, sql, sonarqube, sql-injection

I have a query string like -

```
queryStr.append(" ").append(relation.getJoins()[i].getChildSql()).append(" = :join").append(i);
```

I am using setParameter to set value of **:join** but Sonar complains possibility of SQL injection. Is it not allowed to append values in setParameter as below -

```
 for (int i = 0; i < parentKeyValues.length; i++) {
                    query.setParameter("join" + i, parentKeyValues[i]);
                }
```

Comment: What does `relation.getJoins()[i].getChildSql()` return? Is **any** of it user-supplied content? (Or does `queryStr` contain any user-supplied content?)

Comment: It returns another query string which does not contain any user supplied content. Neither does queryStr contain any other user-supplied content apart from **:join**

Comment: A more complete example would probably help, but it sounds fine (but I'm not a Sonarcube guy). Sonar is probably just seeing the string manipulation and making a (reasonable) assumption. :-)

Comment: If we let aside sonarqube for a moment then can we say that **"join" + i** in **query.setParameter("join" + i, parentKeyValues[i]);** is SQL injection safe considering there is no other user-supplied parameter ?

Comment: If you're only setting user-supplied content via `setParameter`, then yes, it should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

SQL injection is possible in:

```
.append(relation.getJoins()[i].getChildSql())
```

only when `getChildSql()` may return any kind of user provided data.

```
.append(" = :join").append(i)
```

only when `i` is something else than an integer and may contain user provided data.

I don't think that `setParameter()` could be exploited.